# VLOOKUP based conditional formatting highlights the cell above the intended one

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to a column in Excel using the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" feature.

In Sheet 1 have a list of names in column A with corresponding reference numbers in column B. In Sheet 2 I have a longer list of reference numbers in column C. I want the conditional formatting rule to look up the reference numbers in Sheet 1 against those in the Sheet 2 and highlight the cell where they is an overlap.

I have found an apparent solution to this using a vlookup as the formula:

```
=$B2=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet2!$C:$C,1,FALSE)
```

This works in that cells in Sheet 1 have the correct formatting applied, but all the cells have been shifted up by one ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIhzm.png)). I have copied the highlighted reference numbers out and done a lookup against the reference numbers in sheet 2 to double-check and the top one highlighted isn't in Sheet 2 but the one below the filled cells is ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AdD4.png)).

I have tried replacing the vlookup in the conditional formatting with an INDEX/MATCH function in case there was a problem with the VLOOKUP but the result was the same: `=$B2=INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$C:$C,0))`

I've tried removing the spaces between the xx and numbers in the references based on a different stackoverflow answer, but no luck. I've also tried changing the format of the cells from General to Text with the same result.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created this on the entire column B so the **Applies to:** is B:B. The formula references B**2** but it is relatively referenced to B1. The highlights will always be applied to the cell one row below. Here are some solutions:

1. Change the **Applies to:** to `=$B$2:INDEX($B:$B, MATCH("zzz", $A:$A))`. This will resolve to the correct range and will not stay as a formula. You will need to have a look at the formula after you apply this to ensure that hte `xlA1` references have not adjusted to teh new range.
2. Change the formula to ignore the first row. e.g. `=AND(ROW()>1, ISNUMBER(MATCH($B1, SHeet2!$C:$C, 0)))`. No further adjustment should be necessary and the fuill column Applies to: is valid..

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  Both the vlookup and the index match are throwing an error.  Wrapping it in the iferror function should fix that.

```
=$B2=iferror(VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet2!$C:$C,1,FALSE),0)
```