# Can I do conditional formatting on a table of text based on vlookup with text result from another cell not within the table?

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting

For example I have a table of names that is a rota, and in a cell next to the rota there is a VLOOKUP searching an annual leave table and with the result of the VLOOKUP being the name of a person who is on leave on the annual leave rota.
I then wanted a strikethrough the name conditional formatting on the table if they were the result of the VLOOKUP showing that they were on leave.

My VLOOKUP formula that I have in a cell next to weekly rota shows which staff member is on leave. I have tried referencing just that cell in the conditional formatting e.g. strikethrough in the table if it matches that cell, but it doesn't work, I'm assuming because it has a formula and not just text :(

Is there not a way to do conditional formatting using a cell that contains a text result from a formula?

Comment: Can you be more specifc? Did you try [VLOOKUP based conditional formatting highlights the cell above the intended one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661357/vlookup-based-conditional-formatting-highlights-the-cell-above-the-intended-one?rq=2)?